# AngularJS : The correct way to factory returning object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have a POST data to retrive in a Angular.js project. This is my factory:

```
angular.module('mtApp').factory('getKey', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(data) {
            var key='';
            return $http({
                url: '../php/key_gen.php',
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }).success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data); //value is right as expected
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('Erro : ' + status + ' ' + headers);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

The way I´m getting the data is:

```
$scope.key = 'ok';

getKey.getData()
.success(function($scope,data){
    $scope.key = data.GeneratedKey;
    console.log(data.GeneratedKey); //undefined
    console.log(data);  //200 o.O
});

console.log($scope.key); //still 'ok' O.o
```

As you can see in my code I have several console.log calls. When I run the application the only thing I see is:

```
mtapp.controller.js:13 ok
mtapp.app.js:52 Object {GeneratedKey: "d1bc7a5e840a6c24d87b90dde9e075de1f0e3b34978ca9f319…69d839b4e2a004e1f8d728939867afe189cfb8848c6a8ee38"}
mtapp.controller.js:9 undefined
mtapp.controller.js:10 200
```

The value in line mtapp.app.js:52 should be the same as mtapp.controller.js:10. But the object from the factory has only a value of 200 when I try to view in the log...

My objective is get the value from the JSON in the factory (**GeneratedKey**) to the controller (**in the $scope.key**).

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: why are you accepting the first argument of the success callback as $scope? Judging by the callback you used in your factory, you know that should be data instead... the second argument is the status code.

Comment: I should be `.success(function(data,$scope){` ?

Comment: `.success(function(data, statusCode){`

Comment: Not working yet. The line `console.log($scope.key); //still 'ok' O.o` still printing only 'ok'.

Comment: it's supposed to print 'ok'. ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Note the order of the logs that appear in your console

Comment: why do you have "return data;" in your success callback? Does this do anything? Do you expect it to do anything?

Comment: I expect to return the data when I call the GetKey in the controller

Answer (score 2):

Because you are dealing with second parameter which is status code, you should remove `$scope` from there and use `data` itself

**Code**

```
getKey.getData()
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){ <---here $scope should remove
    $scope.key = data.GeneratedKey;
    console.log(data.GeneratedKey);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That´s the problem. But I just don´t know why I have used this. Problably a wrong use of an example. :(

Comment: @dipievil What example? Have you tried to read documentation – https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski It was pretty straight forward

Comment: There´s still a problem. 
 `$scope.key = '';
 getKey.getData()
 .success(function(data){
  $scope.key = data.GeneratedKey;
  console.log(data.GeneratedKey);
 });
 
 console.log($scope.key);`

$scope.key still empty. I think that´s why I put $scope in the call.

Comment: @dipievil you should not pass `$scope` to the service

Answer (score 0):

As **Kevin** said the main problem is the asynchronous way that angular.js works.

Só the big  problem is that the last line

```
console.log($scope.key); //still 'ok' O.o
```

need to be set before the end of the function that call the factory. And the $scope has been removed from the function to work properly as **pankajparkar** said.

```
$scope.key = 'ok';

getKey.getData()
.success(function(data){ // removed the $scope
    $scope.key = data.GeneratedKey;
    console.log($scope.key); //Moved up and it shows correctly in the console
    ... the rest of my code ...
});
```

I don´t know if it is the best solution, but works now! :D

Comment: You miss the part that Kevin said.

Comment: are you talking about asynchronous part? that was obvious while you are making ajax?

Answer (score -1):

Try using $q in your factory instead.

```
angular.module('mtApp').factory('getKey', function($http, $q) {
    var  getData= function(data) {
            var key='';
            var url = '../php/key_gen.php';
            var returned = $http.post(url, data);
            return $q.all(returned);

        };
     var getKey = {
    getData: getData

  };


  return getKey;
});


$scope.key = 'ok';

getKey.getData(someData).then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(response.data.GeneratedKey);
});
```

Comment: Don´t know why the someData. I want to get the data FROM the factory, not to send to it. Removing it I got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'GeneratedKey' of undefined`

Comment: your getData accepts a parameter hence the someData. You should be able to get your GEneratedKey from response. What does response.data return in the console?

Comment: This is an anti-patern. There is no reason to unwrap a promise just to wrap it again. Just return the promise returned by `$http.post(...)`

Comment: `someData` is a variable?!

Comment: If you dont need a parameter in getData, you'll need to remove it in your factory. So yes, it is a variable.